# Transition not working when clicking element with click() function

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I've got a basic show / hide alpine component with transition. Everything works as expected when I click the button with my mouse.

```
<div x-data="{ open: false }">
<button x-on:click="open = ! open">OPEN</button>
<div x-show="open"
     x-transition:enter="ease-in-out duration-500"
     x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0"
     x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100"
     x-transition:leave="ease-in-out duration-500"
     x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100"
     x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0">
    CONTENT
</div>
</div>
```

However I am trying to update the alpine state from another JS event. I am doing this by calling:

btn.click();

The content is displayed however I don't see the transition when opening the content this way? The transition only works when clicking the btn manually.

How can I ensure the transition works?

I'm not sure whether there is another way of doing this? I tried looking into how to update the state to try and get it to open rather than using click event such as:

```
return pb_edit_slideout_btn.__x.$data.show = true;
```

and also tried to register component manally like:

```
<section x-data="editSlideOut()" x-cloak>
    .....
</section>

function editSlideOut() {
    return {
        show: false,
        open() { this.show = true },
        close() { this.show = false },
        isOpen() { return this.show === true },
    }
}
```

and then trying to call it to change state like:

```
let edit = editSlideOut();
edit.open();
```

Any ideas where I may be going wrong? How can I trigger the state change / click to run the transaction from directly in a JS event function?

Comment: Could you create a live example of your problem? I cannot reproduce it with a simple `onclick="let el = getElementById('the_button_id'); el.click()"` on a different button element. The transition is working fine for me.

Comment: Hi @dauros, I've created a codepen, hope it helps :)
https://codepen.io/l4k3y/pen/ExRerJr

Comment: The second button also has a `@click="show = !show"`, so you are triggering the click event twice.